# What is the type/instance of a redux thunk promise error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am using typescript + redux/toolkit to create thunks to handle my API fetching in my react app

This is the thunk:

```
export const doSomethingThunk = createAppAsyncThunk(
  'do/Something',
  async (args: Param.DoSomething, store) => {
    try {
      return await claimApi.claimMintLink(args);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof ApiException) {
        return store.rejectWithValue({
          msg: e.msg,
          code: e.code,
        });
      }

      return store.rejectWithValue({
        msg: 'Unknown API exception',
        code: 0,
      });
    }
  }
);
```

And then I call this thunk inside my react component. The doSomethingThunk is chained with .unwrap() so this dispatch action will throw an exception to the catch block if something goes wrong.

```
      try {
        await dispatch(
          doSomethingThunk(args)
        ).unwrap();

        navigate('/verify', { replace: true });
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof ??? ) {
            // if the instance of error is from rejectWithValue, handle the error
        }
      }
```

My question is what is the instanceof/type I should be using to check whether or not the exception is from the rejectWithValue()?

I have tried importing SerializedError from the package but it is just a typescript interface so I could not check the error instance using that.